# Selenium ActionDriver.click not working in Firefox

Tags: firefox, selenium

I've got a test where I need to use the action click.  I can't directly click the element I need because it's a ::before element, and the element it's before is 0x14 so it's not interactable.  I'm using watir-webdriver instead of selenium directly, which is why `wd` is used.  It accesses Selenium's objects instead of Watir's.

I have an element, I am going to use the parent to find the location I need to click.

```rb
$browser.wd.action
  .move_to(element.parent.wd)
  .move_by(12, 0)
  .click
  .perform
```

This code works fine in Chrome, however nothing gets clicked in Firefox.  Both zooms are set to 100%.  Relative to the parent, the object I need to click is in the same place.

I don't know where else to look.

I've tried this with: Selenium 2.42 on Firefox 29 and Selenium 2.44 on Firefox 34.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE

---

I've downgraded to FF 31.1.1 and have changed my Driver instantiation code to include native events:

```
if $BROWSER == :firefox
  profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
  profile.native_events = true
  return Watir::Browser.new $BROWSER, profile: profile
else
  return Watir::Browser.new $BROWSER
end
```

No luck with click.

I'm trying it on a website where I can see mouse movement and clicking: http://www.escapemotions.com/experiments/flame/.  It's an interactive drawing program.  The mouse moves just fine, click_and_hold seems to work,and drag_and_drop_by works fine too.  I run into trouble on click.

Chaining click_and_hold.release works.  I'm going to submit a defect for 2.44.

Comment: Please check whether native events are enabled for Firefox? And also try Firefox 32 or 33 with Selenium 2.44 (in this version, native event support is not there for Firefox 34)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a defect.  As a work around click_and_hold and release can be chained to simulate a click.

```
driver.action.click_and_hold.release.perform
```

The defect is logged: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=8353

Comment: I took a look at the script you submitted with your bug report. If you increase `sleep 1` to a much longer value (e.g. `sleep 5`) does it behave as you expect? If yes, I've got an explanation for you. (I can't easily test it myself as I don't use Ruby.)

Comment: The increase in sleep doesn't change the behavior.

Comment: Well, then, I don't know what is going on there. On my system, and converting your script to Python, I can reproduce your issue by messing with the length of sleep in (the Python-equivalent of) the `sleep 1` line. A longer sleep time makes the issue go away.

Comment: Another thing that occurred to me. If you add just after the line where you create your driver the command `puts driver.capabilities[:native_events]` (which I believe is the way you'd check whether native events are on or off using Ruby), is it true or false? Note that even if you request native events to be on, Selenium will silently ignore the flag if it turns out that it cannot use native events.

Comment: In the script I wrote, I set native_events to true for the profile and passed that into the driver.
https://gist.github.com/aaronhumerickhouse/9661a75419b93482a6fc

Comment: Yes, I saw that. Let me repeat what I said in my previous comment, with added emphasis: "Note that **even if** you request native events to be on, Selenium will **silently ignore** the flag **if** it turns out that it cannot use native events." It does not matter if you turn it on but Selenium cannot honor it. Not all combinations of Selenium and FF can support native events. For instance, I've just tried Selenium 2.44 with FF 34 (like you did) and even if I request native events, I do not **in fact** get native events.